# Can I pass an array to a lambda such that I can use sizeof()

Tags: c++

I'm replacing some #defines with lambdas in my code. I have a bunch of structures which are the result of shader compilation, declared like so:

```
const BYTE ShaderByteCode[] = 
{
     68,  88,  66,  67, 233, 176, 
     42,  49,  64,  77, 131, 190, 
     75,  97, 214,  59, 236, 203, 
    188, 191,   1,   0,   0,   0, 
    etc...
};
```

A #define has `ShaderByteCode` as an input, and calls `SetPixelShader`, which takes the size of the byte array as a parameter:

```
#define doThing(Thing, ShaderByteCode) \
Thing.SetPixelShader(ShaderByteCode, sizeof(ShaderByteCode) ); \
```

Using a lambda, like this:

```
auto doThing = [](Thing& thing, const BYTE ShaderByteCode[]) {
        thing.SetPixelShader(ShaderByteCode, sizeof(ShaderByteCode));
    };
```

I will just get a pointer to the start of the array and `sizeof()` returns the size of the pointer.
Is there a way I can pass a single parameter into the lambda, or do I need to do what I'm currently doing and pass the size in separately?

Comment: `ShaderByteCode` is `const`, so why don't you just count it?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but can you elaborate?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of the C style array ? Then the size/length will always be available.

Comment: the compiler I'm working with generates the byte code as above. I'm asking the question to know whether technically I can do what I'm asking, specifically. 
I know I'd be better off not using an array at all :-D
It's more for curiosity's sake, could I replicate the inputs to the #define with a lambda?

Comment: e.g. I could pass a reference (&ShaderByteCode)[], but that still doesn't get me what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, maybe a raw array isn't the best thing to pass here.

But you mention a `#define` macro which does the `sizeof`. If you want to keep using this because it's the official method of some API, here are some ways to get an array function parameter. The important thing is, a reference-to-array avoids the array-to-pointer decay step.

If you're using C++20, you can do

```
auto doThing = [] <std::size_t N> (Thing& thing, const BYTE (&ShaderByteCode)[N]) {
    THE_MACRO(thing, ShaderByteCode);
};
```

If you're using C++14 or later,

```
auto doThing = [] (Thing& thing, const auto& ShaderByteCode) {
    using deref_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ShaderByteCode)>;
    static_assert(std::is_array<deref_t>::value &&
                  std::is_same<std::remove_extent_t<deref_t>, const BYTE>::value,
                  "Invalid argument type in doThing lambda");
    THE_MACRO(thing, ShaderByteCode);
};
```

If using C++11, or using C++14-C++17 but you need the functor to be SFINAE-friendly, I don't think it can be done with a lambda, but you could define your own functor class with templated `operator()`.

Comment: This works great, although I think there are a couple of typos, I used: `auto deref_t = std::remove_reference<decltype(ShaderByteCode)>();`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `using deref_t =`.... Yours would make `deref_t` an object whose type is a trait struct, which isn't useful.

Comment: ah, I ignored the assert stuff.. :-D

Comment: In that case you can get rid of the `deref_t` line too.

Comment: ahha, the `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ShaderByteCode)>;` isn't actually removing the reference from `ShaderByteCode`

Comment: More corrections, sorry. And https://godbolt.org/z/a4441x3xb

Answer (score 3):

Use template and let template deduction find size of the array:

```cpp
template<typename T, size_t N>
void doThing(Thing& thing, const T (&shaderByteCode)[N])
{
    thing.SetPixelShader(shaderByteCode, N);
}
```

No macros, no boiler plate, works with quite old C++ standard. C++ will deduce the parameters for you, you do not have to type them explicitly:

```
Thing thing;
doThing(thing, ShaderByteCode);
```

[some demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Weo7dx7jj).

Comment: thanks, but was trying to find out if I can determine the size after passing in the array

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? Invocation: `doThing(thing, someArray);` will just work.

Comment: oh sorry I missed the bit about template deduction, I thought you'd have to call it liek `doThing<BYTE, sizeof(someArray>>(...) or similar. nice!

Answer (score 2):

`decltype` will be your friend.

If you have whatever C-Style array, `decltype` will know the number of members.

For example:

```
using BYTE = unsigned char;
const BYTE ShaderByteCode[] =
{
     68,  88,  66,  67, 233, 176,
     42,  49,  64,  77, 131, 190,
     75,  97, 214,  59, 236, 203,
    188, 191,   1,   0,   0,   0,
    1,2,3
};
using Array = decltype(ShaderByteCode);
```

Array will be of type `const unsigned char[27];`

And with that you can pass this element per reference (or pointer) to a function or to a lambda.

This could look like for example this:

```
#include <iostream>

using BYTE = unsigned char;
const BYTE ShaderByteCode[] =
{
     68,  88,  66,  67, 233, 176,
     42,  49,  64,  77, 131, 190,
     75,  97, 214,  59, 236, 203,
    188, 191,   1,   0,   0,   0,
    1,2,3
};
using Array = decltype(ShaderByteCode);

void SetPixelShader(Array& sbc) {
    std::cout << sizeof(sbc) << '\t' << sizeof(Array) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    auto doThing = [](const Array& SBC) { SetPixelShader(SBC);};
    doThing(ShaderByteCode);
}
```